# Returning the highest 6 names in a List of tuple in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Please I want to return first 6 names (only the names) with the highest corresponding integers from the list of tuple below.
I have been able to return all the names from highest (sms) to lowest (boss).

```
[('sms', 10), ('bush', 9), ('michaels', 7), ('operations', 6), ('research', 5), ('code', 4), ('short', 3), ('ukandu', 2), ('technical', 1), ('apeh', 1), ('boss', 1)]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

`heapq.nlargest` is what you want here:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter
largest_names = [x[0] for x in heapq.nlargest(6,your_list,key=itemgetter(1))]
```

It will be more efficient than sorting as it only takes the biggest elements and discards the rest.  Of course, it is less efficient than slicing if the list is pre-sorted for other reasons.

Complexity:

- heapq: O(N)
- sorting: O(NlogN)
- slicing (only if pre-sorted): O(6)

Explanation:

```
heapq.nlargest(6,your_list,key=itemgetter(1))
```

This line returns a list of (name,value) tuples, but only the 6 biggest ones -- comparison is done by the second (index=1 --> `key=itemgetter(1)`) element in the tuple.

The rest of the line is a list-comprehension over the 6 biggest name,value tuples which only takes the name portion of the tuple and stores it in a list.

---

It might be of interest to you that you could store this data as a `collections.Counter` as well.

```
d = collections.Counter(dict(your_list))
biggest = [x[0] for x in d.most_common(6)]
```

It's probably not worth converting just to do this calculation (that's what heapq is for after all ;-), but it might be worth converting to make the data easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

```
data=[('sms', 10), ('bush', 9), ('michaels', 7), ('operations', 6), ('research', 5), ('code', 4), ('short', 3), ('ukandu', 2), ('technical', 1), ('apeh', 1), ('boss', 1)]
return [x[0] for x in sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0:6]]
```

Which does following:

- `sorted` returns data sorted using `key` function. Since standard sorting order is from ascending, `reverse=True` sets it do descending;
- `lambda x: x[1]` is anonymous function which returns second element of the argument (of a tuple in this case); `itemgetter(1)` is nicer way to do this, but requires additional imports;
- `[0:6]` slices first 6 elements of the list;
- `[x[0] for x in ... ]` creates a list of first elements of each passed tuple;

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain your code. It might be hard for beginners to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is already sorted simply slice off the first six tuples and then get the names:

```
first_six = data[0:6]  # or data[:6]
only_names = [entry[0] for entry in first_six]
```

The list comprehension can be unrolled to:

```
only_names = []
for entry in first_six:
    only_names.append(entry[0])
```

If the list is *not* already sorted you can use the `key` keyword argument of the `sort` method (or the `sorted` built-in) to sort by score:

```
data.sort(key=lambda entry: entry[1], reverse=True)
```

`lambda` is an anonymous function - the equivalent is:

```
def get_score(entry):
    return entry[1]

data.sort(key=get_score, reverse=True)
```